# How to re-start html to recommend css codes

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

When I first started making html files via atom.
atom automatically recommended codes for CSS.

For example,
When I type,

bor

then, it automatically showed completed codes such as border, border-right, so on.

However, From somepoint,
when I create new html files,
this feature no longer appears to be active.
It does not recommend codes anymore.

How can I make it possbile again?

Comment: Have you installed any plugins between when it worked and when it stopped working?

Comment: It looks as though this problem isn't to do with html or css but with the atom editor. Re-tagging the question to reflect this might help get someone who understands atom to help you.